# How to fix error during undistortion for deeplabcut 3D?

Tags: python

After performing the following steps:

```
# check if corners can be detected
deeplabcut.calibrate_cameras(config_path3d,cbrow=10,cbcol=7,calibrate=False,alpha=0.4)

# Calibrate model deeplabcut.calibrate_cameras(config_path3d,cbrow=10,cbcol=7,calibrate=True,alpha=0.4)
```

which run without issues, I want to run the check undistortion code:

```
# check the distortion import matplotlib import cv2 %matplotlib inline

deeplabcut.check_undistortion(config_path3d)
```

but then I get the following error:

```
\`error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[19\], line 6
3 import cv2
4 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
\----\> 6 deeplabcut.check_undistortion(config_path3d)

File \~.conda\\envs\\DEEPLABCUT\\lib\\site-packages\\deeplabcut\\pose_estimation_3d\\camera_calibration.py:378, in check_undistortion(config, cbrow, cbcol, plot)
376 h, w = img1.shape\[:2\]
377 \_, corners1 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray1, (cbcol, cbrow), None)
\--\> 378 corners_origin1 = cv2.cornerSubPix(
379     gray1, corners1, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria
380 )
382 # Remapping dataFrame_camera1_undistort
383 im_remapped1 = cv2.remap(img1, map1_x, map1_y, cv2.INTER_LANCZOS4)

error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\\a\\opencv-python\\opencv-python\\opencv\\modules\\imgproc\\src\\cornersubpix.cpp:58: error: (-215:Assertion failed) count \>= 0 in function 'cv::cornerSubPix'\`
```

Undistortion of images for deeplabcut 3d

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the number of rows and columns in the code:

```
# check the distortion
import matplotlib
import cv2
%matplotlib inline

deeplabcut.check_undistortion(config_path3d,cbrow=10,cbcol=7)
```